# Javascript Confirm, Running form even if canceled

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I have an ajax form handler that deletes a payment method. When the user clicks "delete" it shows a confirmation popup. However, even if the user clicks "cancel" it still runs the form and deletes the payment method.  What do I need to change?

HTML:

```
<form class="sg-inline-form" method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="sg_customer_id" value="customerID">
  <input type="hidden" name="sg_card_id" value="cardID">
  <a href="#" class="delete-card" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$('.delete-card').click(function() {
    $('.ajax-loading').show();
    const $form = $(this).parent();
    const customer = $form.find('input[name=sg_customer_id]').val();
    const card = $form.find('input[name=sg_card_id]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: sg_obj.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action': 'sg_delete_payment_source',
            'customer' : customer,
            'card' : card
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
          $('.ajax-loading').hide();
          $('#ajax-messages').addClass('alert alert-success').html('The payment source has been deleted. <a href=".">Refresh Page</a>');
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
          $('.ajax-loading').hide();
          $('#ajax-messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').html('An error occurred.');
        }
    });  
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not make the two separate onClick bindings. You can do your functionality by changing you code like this

HTML:

```
<form class="sg-inline-form" method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="sg_customer_id" value="customerID">
  <input type="hidden" name="sg_card_id" value="cardID">
  <a href="#" class="delete-card">Delete</a>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$('.delete-card').click(function() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        $('.ajax-loading').show();
        const $form = $(this).parent();
        const customer = $form.find('input[name=sg_customer_id]').val();
        const card = $form.find('input[name=sg_card_id]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: sg_obj.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': 'sg_delete_payment_source',
                'customer' : customer,
                'card' : card
            },
            success:function(data) {
                // This outputs the result of the ajax request
              $('.ajax-loading').hide();
              $('#ajax-messages').addClass('alert alert-success').html('The payment source has been deleted. <a href=".">Refresh Page</a>');
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
              $('.ajax-loading').hide();
              $('#ajax-messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').html('An error occurred.');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This works also! Sorry I saw the other answer before yours. This one seems a bit cleaner.

Comment: @RiotAct This answer is also a direct implementation of the code you provided and is better in quality than mine while still using the same functionality...

Comment: I changed it to the correct answer. Thanks so much for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using listening to the onclick and the .click events. You can put the confirm in an if to stop on the user clicking "Cancel".

```js
$(function(){
  $("#continues").click(
    function(){
      alert("FIRES EITHER WAY");
  });
  
  $("#stops").click(function(){
    if(confirm("TEST")){
      alert("CONTINUED");
    } else {
      alert("STOPED");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="continues" href="#" onclick="return confirm('Continues')">Continues</a>
<a id="stops" href="#">Stops</a>
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks! One other follow up question: does this work on Mac as well? The whole popup alert thing I mean.

Comment: It works on any browser on any machine, as long as JavaScript is enabled in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a condition to test what the confirm() actually says. [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/728900/How-to-get-the-javascript-confirmation-alert-respo) shows how to get the actual `confirm()` response and you should test if the response was true or false before submitting the `$.ajax` request